# Want to add click event on polygon in bing map

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I want to draw polygons using drawing manager as I also want to edit them. The issue is that once I click on polygon its not showing an alert message. It seems click event is not getting fired.

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'
});
var center = map.getCenter();
var nose = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(center, null);
var polygon1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon([
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 0.01, center.longitude - 0.03),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 0.01, center.longitude - 0.11),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 0.05, center.longitude - 0.07)
]);
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(polygon1, 'click', function () { alert('polygonClick1'); });
var polygon2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon([
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 0.01, center.longitude + 0.03),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 0.01, center.longitude + 0.11),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 0.05, center.longitude + 0.07)
]);
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(polygon2, 'click', function () { alert('polygonClick2'); });
var mouth = new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline([
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude - 0.02, center.longitude - 0.10),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude - 0.05, center.longitude - 0.07),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude - 0.05, center.longitude + 0.07),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude - 0.02, center.longitude + 0.10)
]);
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools', function () {
var tools = new Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools(map);
    tools.showDrawingManager(function (manager) {
    manager.setPrimitives([mouth]);
    manager.add(polygon1);
    manager.add(polygon2);
    manager.add(nose);
});
});
```

Comment: And what is the problem? describe your desired result and problem

Comment: Once I click on polygon its not showing alert message. It seems click event is not getting fired. Pls help

Comment: I have click events working with polygon. When I am binding the polygon with drawingmanager its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to be expected as you are adding the polygons to the drawing manager and not to the map. The drawing manager handles uses all the mouse events for editing and drawing and doesn't allow any custom events to be added to the shapes. The drawing manager itself has a number of events which you can use instead as documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750462.aspx

Since these are already defined shapes, what you can do instead of using the drawing manager/toolbar, is use the DrawingTools class on it's own. You can pass in the polygon into the edit function when you want to edit it. Perhaps when the user clicks on the polygon, go into edit mode. Then you can decide how you want editing to stop, perhaps when the user presses the esc key. Here is a code sample that shows how to do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type='text/javascript'
            src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap'
            async defer></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var map;
    var tools;

    function GetMap() {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
            credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'
        });

        //Load the DrawingTools module.
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools', function () {
            //Create an instance of the DrawingTools class and bind it to the map.
            tools = new Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools(map);
        });

        //Create a random 5 sided polyogn that fills a decent portion of the map.
        var polygon = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getPolygons(1, map.getBounds(), 5, 0.8);
        map.entities.push(polygon);

        //When the polygon is clicked, go into edit mode.
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(polygon, 'click', function () {
            //Remove the polygon from the map as the drawing tools will display it in the drawing layer.
            map.entities.remove(polygon);

            //Pass the polygon to the drawing tools to be edited.
            tools.edit(polygon);
        });

        //When the user presses 'esc', take the polygon out of edit mode and re-add to base map.
        document.getElementById('myMap').onkeypress = function (e) {
            if (e.charCode === 27) {
                tools.finish(function (s) {
                    map.entities.push(s);
                });
            }
        };
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```